# Power BI - How to partition & aggregate data for a clustered column chart?

Tags: powerbi, dax, visualization, powerbi-desktop

In my data model I have a table that looks a bit like this:

| Customer | Demographic | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | AA | 10 |
| B | AA | 15 |
| C | BB | 20 |
| D | CC | 30 |

I want to create a clustered column chart in my report that shows sum of sales for each demographic. So in the example above the chart would show 3 bars:

- AA = 25
- BB = 20
- CC = 30

Does anyone know if it is possible to do this without having to create a measure summing up sales for each demographic please?

The reason I'd prefer to do it another way is that in the actual table there are 14 different values in the demographics column and 10 different KPIS in addition to sales, which each need their own chart. 140 measures is a lot to create!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a single measure. Is that what you want?

[image]